# Responsive jQuery sketch application failing when div size is < 7px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a responsive sketch application with jQuery.  It works, except for when the size for the divs within the .box class become less than 7px.  I tried to make a fiddle but I couldn't see any output. I'll just leave the code here and hope for the best!

```js
    var wide = 150;

    $(document).ready(function() {
      makeGrid(wide);
      $('body').on('mousedown mouseup', function mouseState(e) {
        if (e.type == "mousedown") {
          $(".box").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
          });
        } else {
          $(".box").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        }
      });
    });

    var makeGrid = function(wide) {
      var boxSide = calculateBoxSide(wide);
      var boxRowNumber = calculateRowNumbers(boxSide);
      var boxSideLength = boxSide + "px";
      $("body").css("line-height", boxSideLength);
      for (i = 0; i < wide; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < boxRowNumber; j++) {
          $box = $('<div class="box">').appendTo(".sketchpad")
          $box.css("width", boxSideLength);
          $box.css("height", boxSideLength);
        }
      }
    }

    var calculateBoxSide = function(wide) {
      return $(".sketchpad").width() / wide;
    }

    var calculateRowNumbers = function(boxSideLength) {
      return Math.round($(".sketchpad").height() / boxSideLength);
    }
```

```css
.sketchpad {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.box:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sketchpad"></div>
```

Comment: Also `var wide;` will be set by users to increase the resolution of their canvas.

Comment: so just set  a min-width and min-height on those so they cant become that small?

Comment: @Rooster that's what I'll do if I can't get this fixed.  I'm really confused as to why this is happening.